# HBase/Hive table queried from Squirrel SQL - Error in loading storage handler.org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler

Tags: hive, hbase, squirrel-sql

I am trying to query a HBase table through Squirrel SQL. Created a Hive external table like the following

```
create external table tweets_hbase(key string, value string)
stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
with serdeproperties ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,data:tweet_text")
tblproperties ("hbase.table.name" = "tweets_hbase")
```

I am able to query through command line HIVE

```
hive> select * from tweets_hbase;
OK
20160725001730109       {"createdat":"25-Jul-2016 12:17:03","tweet_date":"2016-07-25","text":"私のランドールスゴビ:) \n#abyssrium\nhts:t.co/NcKtQi9lzm ht/t.co/WNgQIxLU05","user":"uw_kyaaaan","uniqueid":1469420239464,"searchtag":"Apple"}
20160725001730266       {"createdat":"25-Jul-2016 12:17:03","tweet_date":"2016-07-25","text":"2016年7月24日\n8422 Steps\n移動距離 6.485 km\n消費カロリー 467.6 kcal\n\n#M7POPOPO ht/t.co/eFathZXTHD","user":"matsuwichi","uniqueid":1469420239465,"searchtag":"Apple"}
20160725001730308       {"createdat":"25-Jul-2016 12:17:03","tweet_date":"2016-07-25","text":"RT @JBCrewdotcom: Don't forget to leave a nice review for #Coldwater after purchasing! \niTunes: t.co/p5YKRwPKNw\nGoogle Play: ht\u2026","user":"2016OLLGAndUGRL","uniqueid":1469420239466,"searchtag":"Apple"}
```

However when i try to query through Squirrel SQL, i get an Error in loading. The necessary JARs have been added to Extra Class Path.

> 1. hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0.jar
> 2. hbase-client-1.1.5.jar
> 3. hbase-common-1.1.5.jar
> 4. hbase-protocal-1.1.5.jar
> 5. hbase-server-1.1.5.jar
> 6. hive-jdbc-1.1.1-standalone.jar

Please help

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error in loading storage handler.org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:296)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.StatementWrapper.execute(StatementWrapper.java:165)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.SQLExecuterTask.processQuery(SQLExecuterTask.java:369)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.SQLExecuterTask.run(SQLExecuterTask.java:212)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.util.TaskExecuter.run(TaskExecuter.java:82)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself. The following is what I had to do:

1. Upgrade HBase to 1.2.2
2. While starting thriftServer start with the following jars with --jars option

> ./start-thriftserver.sh --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10001
>   --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  --hiveconf spark.cores.max=2 --master spark://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7077 --name
>   ThriftServer --jars
>   file:///home/hadoop/software/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/lib/hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1.jar,file:///home/hadoop/software/hbase-1.2.2/lib/hbase-common-1.2.2.jar,file:///home/hadoop/software/hbase-1.2.2/lib/hbase-protocol-1.2.2.jar,file:///home/hadoop/software/hbase-1.2.2/lib/hbase-client-1.2.2.jar,file:///home/hadoop/software/hbase-1.2.2/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar,file:///home/hadoop/software/hbase-1.2.2/lib/hbase-server-1.2.2.jar,file:///home/hadoop/software/hbase-1.2.2/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar,file:///home/hadoop/software/hbase-1.2.2/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar

Comment: Please make sure in loaded jars hive-hbase-handler.jar is loaded 
 (usually /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-hbase-handler.jar )
https://community.datafabric.hpe.com/s/question/0D50L00006BIsl5SAD/hbase-stroage-handler-error-when-using-spark-sql-for-hive-external-table-on-maprdb